# Need Advise On Copying HTML Content

Tags: html

I have a small question regarding HTML. If let's suppose I have 3 pages: Home, About Us, and Contact Us. If I have a lot of content script on my Home.html file and would like to have the same content replicated on my About Us.html file such as header area and footer let's say, do I have to copy and paste the entire script to the About Us.html file excluding the body section which usually differs? That would take a lot of time if I have over 50 pages. And what if I had to fix something in the Home.html file, I will also have to alter these changes manually on every single page. I think that would be very time-consuming. Is there any alternative option for this issue?

Comment: What technology stack are you using.

Comment: You can use javascript v.gr. to include the header and the footer from another file.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good method, but if you can use php or other server languages, you can create a 'header.php' file in which you put your header, and include this file in your pages

Comment: Scripts in separate files. Then import them in all HTML files.

Comment: You need to use `master-page` concept.

Comment: Thx for all of your suggestions. That is what i was thinking.

Comment: Another way is to use Ajax to dynamically change page content without redirecting user. It's an easy way for page updates and will look nicer too

Comment: Is it only HTML or any server side technology you will be using? If its only HTML look for shtml (Server enable needed). Otherwise server side all technologies have user controls or partial views for this purpose.

Comment: @Sunil — If someone picks HTML from "HTML or any server side technology", then Server Side Includes are not an option because that's a server side technology!

Comment: using only HTML. will look deeper into shtml.